# pass parameter to UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ios6, uitapgesturerecognizer

i have created dynamic `UIimage` view and and `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view its look like this

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 200, 150)];
        NSString *ImageURL = [str objectForKey:@"imageLink"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
        image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];

        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [documentory addSubview:image];
```

and my action method like this

```
-(void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

}
```

i want to pass a string parameters to tapDetected method can anyone tell me how to do this thank you very much

Comment: what you need to pass there?

Comment: I'm not sure we can add a parameter to the gestureRecognizer properties. From which element do you want to get a string ?

Comment: take one global variable and change the value of that variable as you want.

Comment: i want to pass the imageUrl and some string parameters along with it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can extend a UITapGestureRecognizer for holding more data:

```
// MYTapGestureRecognizer.h

@interface MYTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *data;

@end


// MYTapGestureRecognizer.m

@implementation MYTapGestureRecognizer

@end


// =====================

....

MYTapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[MYTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];

singleTap.data = @"Hello";

.....


// ====================

-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {

MYTapGestureRecognizer *tap = (MYTapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer;

NSLog(@"data : %@", tap.data);

}
```

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking.

Answer (score 6):

Pass the sender,

```
- (void)tapDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", sender.view);   // imageview 
}
```