# What happens when a parametrized selector is called with no parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was going over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703767/pass-parameter-to-uitapgesturerecognizer) example in which a selector is used. I have copied the code from there for convenience.

```
// MYTapGestureRecognizer.h

@interface MYTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *data;

@end


// MYTapGestureRecognizer.m

@implementation MYTapGestureRecognizer

@end


// =====================

....

MYTapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[MYTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];

singleTap.data = @"Hello";

.....


// ====================

-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {

MYTapGestureRecognizer *tap = (MYTapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer;

NSLog(@"data : %@", tap.data);

}
```

My question is

1-When `self` calls the selector what parameter does it pass in the above case ?

2-  Also if a selector (pointing to a method that requires parameters) is called (see example below) and no parameters are passed are there any defaults in that case ?  If possible is there any documentation for that ?

Suppose the signature of MyTest is

```
- (void) MyTest : (NSString*) a;
```

Now constructing and calling a selector

```
SEL a = NSSelectorFromString(@"MyTest:");

    [t performSelector:a]; //Works Fine and the call is made - However Notice no parameter is passed . In this case what would the value of the parameter be in the method ?
```

I checked the following but I could not find this information

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html)

[Rys Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html)

Comment: How do you think? I think zero. All zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to your questions:-

1. *When self calls the selector what parameter does it pass in the above case ?*

If a tap is detected and the selector is called, the parameter will be an object of `UITapGestureRecognizer`. This will be the same instance on which the tap gesture is detected.

2. *Also if a selector (pointing to a method that requires parameters) is called (see example below) and no parameters are passed are there any defaults in that case ? If possible is there any documentation for that ?*

Why do you want to call the method like that, is there any special purpose?. If not, you can call the method just like

`[self tapDetected:nil];`

or

`[self performSelector:@selector(tapDetected:) withObject:nil];`

If you call the method as provided in the question, most probably it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you want to access that selector via self, use it like :

```
[self tapDetected:nil];
```

You need to handle this case in your selector, like :

```
-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
     if (tapRecognizer)
     {
         MYTapGestureRecognizer *tap = (MYTapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer;

         NSLog(@"data : %@", tap.data);
     }
     else
     {
          //Do your work
     }
}
```

Also not only this, if you are not sure of parameter you are passing change your selector decalartion as `id`, like :

```
 -(void)tapDetected:(id)sender {

     NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([id class]);
     NSLog(@"Object passed is of class : %@", className);         

     //And make check here
     if ([id isKindOfClass:[MYTapGestureRecognizer class]])
     {
          //Do your work here
     }
 }
```

There are no default cases, you need to handle every case manually or else app will crash.

Comment: Since the selector gets invoked behind the scene I wanted to know what parameter is passed to the selector when it is invoked.Also Is there a certain rule that states what parameters should be passed incase a selector is called without parameters ?

Comment: See my edited answer, this way you can identify which class object is passed.

Comment: Update my question to make it more clear. what object is passed when the `tapDetected` method is called ?

Comment: You better try printing your object and its class name in console, this will make you clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to call the method on self, pass nil parameter to it. But i do not understand what purpose is it serving you.

Also if you do not send parameters to your methods, it is going to fail at your builds. You have to pass either the parameter or nil.

Also if your method does not accept nil parameters it might cause an exception - 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Comment: I could call a method and not pass anything. The example I pointed above works fine

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SEL a = NSSelectorFromString(@"MyTest:");
> [t performSelector:a]; //Works Fine and the call is made - However Notice no parameter is passed . In this case what would the value of the parameter be in the method ?
> ```

It will be undefined junk. You have no guarantees about what it might contain. Most likely, it will be an invalid pointer. If you're unlucky, it might be a valid pointer to some arbitrary object and operating on it will corrupt your app's state. If you're lucky, it will crash so you can find the problem.