# Swift 4 using selector with Multiple Parameters

Tags: swift3, selector, swift4

I write with Swift 4 and try to write a function that send  categoryId as action but I couldn't write .I think my syntax is wrong.If I write function without parameters its not a problem but I get error with parameters functions. Could you say me how to use selector?

```
@objc func sendCategoryIdToPackageSelectionVC(categoryId : Int){
        MarketVC.categoryId = categoryId
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sequeGoToPackageSelection", sender: nil)
    }

func addTapFeatures(){
        taplabel1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.sendCategoryIdToPackageSelectionVC(categoryId:2)))
        taplabel1?.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.labelFirst.addGestureRecognizer(taplabel1!)
}
```

I get an error saying that the action selector doesn't refer to any objc method.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43251708/6541007) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814958/6541007). Nothing new in Swift 4 about the usage of `#selector`.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703767/pass-parameter-to-uitapgesturerecognizer

Comment: func sendCategoryIdToPackageSelectionVC(categoryId : Int){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sequeGoToPackageSelection", sender: nil)
  }

  @objc func callMethod(){
    sendCategoryIdToPackageSelectionVC(categoryId: 2)
  }

  func addTapFeatures(){
    taplabel1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.callMethod))
    taplabel1?.cancelsTouchesInView = false
  }

Comment: Thank all of you guys, I noticed that my opinion is wrong . I will use same function again but , this time I use sender : UILabel  in objc function, after that  I control sender.tag which label's belongs to this tag.And I send categoryId according to that Thanks your helps .

Answer (score 2):

i think, you can't directly use selector to pass parameter.
try some thing like this
you should create an @objc method that calls handleTap(modelObj:myModelObj).

```
@objc func someMethod() { // name this properly!
    handleTap(modelObj: myModelObj)
}
```

Then you can pass this as a selector:

```
#selector(someMethod)
```